# Restful response error: invalid api key

Tags: api, rest, meteor, restful-authentication, api-key

I am new to restful api in meteor. I took code from the meteor chef to learn the working of restful api in meteor.

Here is the link: [The Meteor Chef](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/writing-an-api/)

when I run the application on **POSTMAN** every time I get the response Invalid api key `error:401`

```
connection: function( request ) {
    var getRequestContents = API.utility.getRequestContents( request ),
        apiKey             = getRequestContents.api_key,
        validUser          = API.authentication( apiKey );
        console.log(getRequestContents);
    if ( validUser ) {
      // Now that we've validated our user, we make sure to scrap their API key
      // from the data we received. Next, we return a new object containing our
      // user's ID along with the rest of the data they sent.
      delete getRequestContents.api_key;
      return { owner: validUser, data: getRequestContents };
    } else {
      return { error: 401, message: "Invalid API key." };
    }
  },
```

I am using this service on the server-end and getting this error from the else statement. The if statement is not displaying any value even after `console.log`. It just displays null on the server.